# what will be the decomposition of the function $f(x) = i^x$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am just started to learn Complex Analysis.

> We know that every complex valued functions whose domain is also complex number can be decomposed as $f(x)=f_1(x) + i f_2(x)$. Where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are real valued.

**Then my question is what will be the decomposition of the function $f(x) = i^x$ ?**

Please make some edit for me.

Comment: Look up the Moivre formula.

Comment: $f(x)=e^{x\pi i/2}$

Comment: @DinnoKoluh Moivre's formula is applicable for only integers .

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what will be the $f_1(x)$ & $f_2(x)$

Comment: $$i^x = e^{i\pi x/2) = \cos(i\pi x/2)+i\sin(i\pi x/2) $$

Comment: I forgot to write to use Moivre's formula together with Euler's formula which is extended to all numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$i=e^{i\pi /2} = \cos ( \pi/2)+ i \sin (\pi/2) $$, we have  $$i^x=e^{i\pi x /2 } =\cos(\pi x/2 ) + i \sin ( \pi x/2  )$$

Thus $f_1(x) = \cos(\pi x/2 )$ and $f_2(x) = \sin(\pi x/2 )$